# Get the value of an HTML element using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

The following is a response from an Ajax call. How can I select the second and the sixth `<td></td>` element using jQuery and get the value out of it?

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Label 1</td>
            <td>The value I need</td>
            <td>Label2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Label 3</td>
            <td>The value I need</td>
            <td>Label 4</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as jquery:

```
console.log($("td")[1].innerText);
console.log($("td")[5].innerText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for that. Pure Javascript (ES5) works fine. (IE 9+)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].children[1].innerText
```

and

```
document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].children[5].innerText
```

You can read more about [Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), [ParentNode.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) and [Node.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector` to do this:

```
const second = document.querySelector("table tr:first-child td:nth-child(2)").textContent;
const sixth = document.querySelector("table tr:first-child td:nth-child(6)").textContent;
```

---

You could also just get the table, then drill down from there.

```
const table = document.querySelector("table");
const second = table.rows[0].cells[1].textContent;
const sixth = table.rows[0].cells[5].textContent;
```

---

Or jump right to the row, and go from there.

```
const tr = document.querySelector("table tr");
const second = tr.cells[1].textContent;
const sixth = tr.cells[5].textContent;
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not a pure HTML page. It is the response of an Ajax call.

Comment: @Ning: Not sure what you mean. It shouldn't matter where the content is coming from. jQuery is going to use the same native API under the hood.

Comment: I think there is no 'document' to refer to in my case.

Comment: @Ning: Ok, but jQuery selects from `document` when you do `$("td")`. Either way, you can `querySelector` from any element, so if you had some other ancestor of the table, you can select from there. `myContainer.querySelector(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
$("#myHTMLTable tr").each(function(){
        var currentRow=$(this);
    
        var arrayData=[];
        var col2_value=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // for 2nd element
        var col6_value=currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text(); // for 6th element

         var temp_obj={};
        temp_obj.col1=col2_value;
        temp_obj.col2=col6_value;
       
        arrayData.push(obj);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ":nth-child()" selector, so for your case is $("td:nth-child(2)")

Answer (score 0):

```
const tableData = $('td').get(); 
const val_1 = tableData[1].innerText;
const val_2 = tableData[5].innerText;
```

please see: [.get() | jQuery API Doc](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Answer (score -1):

im assuming that what you want to get is not the value but the text content inside the  tag instead. you need to specify an id to your

```
<td id="elem"> this is the value </td>
```

then inside your script do

```
<script>
    $('#elem').text()
</script>
```

make sure to import jquery cdn in your head tag or above the script

Comment: *"you need to specify an id "* ... numerous ways to approach this without needing an ID and that approach is not very scalable for multiple rows

Comment: But your statement that you need an id is not accurate. There are numerous other solutions given here that do not *"need to specify an id"*

Comment: how is that not accurate? does it not solve the problem?

Comment: @charlietfl is right. You don't *"need"* an ID, since there are many other ways to do it. Either way, an "accurate" answer is not always a "good" answer. There are countless accurate solutions that would be abysmal.

Comment: it may not be the best answer but it is accurate. and as i said, the question did not refer to any dynamic scalability because if it is, i would have given a different answer. it is limited only to 2 static elements and so i gave the easiest and shortest answer i can think of